# Android profiler doesn't list all sessions options and only list "No debuggable processes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-profiler

I'm testing phone resource usage using Android Profiler from Android Studio, however I am unable to load session other than the project's own application.
I wanted to see usages of the most popular mobile application, but something is blocking me from loading the sessions of installed application.
I think profiler other application is possible since it's mentioned in the developer.android documentation. https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler?hl=el#advanced-profiling

Picture of list of other process in the standalone Profiler app can be visible here: [Android profiler session options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do4lG.png)

Here we can see numerous session being shown in the dropdown menu. How can I enable it thought a mobile device or a emulator?

Other than that, if there's a way to profile your whole mobile device resource usage than I would be also interested in this.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio Profilers are working with debuggable apps only because it reads some sensitive data, such as the memory content in a heap dump. Therefore, non-debuggable apps don't typically show up in the dropdown menu. This is true for standalone profiler as well.

I believe the screenshot showing a list of other processes probably come from an emulator image of userdebug or eng build. You can check by running command "adb shell getprop | grep ro.build.fingerprint". On those devices, every app was considered debuggable by the system. However, Android Studio would be working in the best-effort mode and some functionality may not work unless the app is inherently debuggable (which means, its APK is built as debuggable).

Regarding the question on whole mobile device resource usage: Sorry, it's currently beyond the scope of Android Studio Profilers as the profilers are designed for the app your are developing. However, please feel free to open a feature request at https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=192708&template=840533.